# D3.js bar chart animation not exiting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a bar chart in D3.js where if a user clicks a p tag that says

> click here to remove bar

then it should remove the left most bar. For the animation I would like the bar to fly off to the left of the screen, and then the other bars are placed into their correct position. The problem though that I am running into is that the right most bar chart is getting removed instead, another bar is pushed outside of the graph and no longer able to be viewed, and it looks like the values of the bars are switched.

I created a jsfiddle that is able to recreate this issue: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/0k0p2krq/)

Here is also the javascript code that is executing the creation, and animation for the bar chart:

```
// chart dimensions
var margin   = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 70 },
    width    =  $('#chart').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
    height   =  $(window).height() / 3.5 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// color palette for graph
var colors = [ '#4398B5', '#ADC4CC', '#92B06A', '#E09D2A', '#DE5F32' ];

var dataset = [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
               .domain( d3.range( dataset.length ) )
               .range( [ 0, width ] )
               .padding( 0.1 );


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain( [ 0, d3.max( dataset )  ] )
               .range( [ height, 0 ] );


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom( xScale );
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft( yScale );

var svg = d3.select( '#chart svg' )
            .attr( 'width'  , width + margin.left + margin.right  )
            .attr( 'height' , height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
            .append( 'g' )
                .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')' );

svg.selectAll( 'rect' )
   .data( dataset )
   .enter()
   .append( 'rect' )
       .attr('x', function ( d, i ) {
            return xScale( i );
       })
       .attr( 'width', xScale.bandwidth() )
       .attr('fill', function( d, i ) {
           return colors[ i ];
       })
       .attr( 'y', function( d, i ) {
           return yScale( d );
       })
       .attr( 'height', function( d ) {
           return height - yScale( d );
       });

svg.append( 'g' )
   .attr( 'class', 'yAxis' )
   .attr( 'transform', 'translate(0, ' + (-1) + ')')
   .call( yAxis );

d3.select("p")
        .on("click", function() {

            dataset.shift();
            //Update scale domains
            xScale.domain( d3.range( dataset.length ) );
            yScale.domain( [ 0 , d3.max( dataset ) ] );

            //Select…
            var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                          .data(dataset );

            bars.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return height - yScale(d);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d);
                });

            bars.exit()
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("x", -xScale.bandwidth())
                .remove();
            });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section of the d3 docs on `.data`'s [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data).

By default, d3 will use **element index** as the key function.  When you `.shift` your data, it thinks the last index is the exiting element since the length decreased by one.  The correct way to fix this is to modify your data so that each datum has some *unique identifier*.  You really want to be data driven here, so I would do something like this:

```
var dataset = [ 
{
  value: 100,
  color: '#4398B5',
  id: 1
},{
  value: 200,
  color: '#ADC4CC',
  id: 2
},{
  value: 300,
  color: '#92B06A',
  id: 3
},{
  value: 400,
  color: '#E09D2A',
  id: 4
},{
  value: 500,
  color: '#DE5F32',
  id: 5
}];
```

Your key function is then:

```
.data( dataset, function(d){ return d.id; } )
```

Note, I added an id into the data, but you could have also just used color, as long as it's unique.

Here's a quick [refactor](https://jsfiddle.net/0k0p2krq/6/) with an improved data array.

Comment: I see, that does make sense. However, even with the refactor it still looks like it is switching the dataset on the bar chart, and is showing the wrong bar to be exiting. Is this still a product of the `.shift` function? I tried using `.splice` instead, and even creating a new array with one element removed, but with no luck.

Comment: @ans, your `y` and `height` calculations are backwards in your update function.  Updated fiddle above.

Comment: Yup that was it! Thanks a bunch!